# Why cant my <a href link work?

Tags: php, html

When i click the link , it cant work.

These are my codes:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql1)) {
    echo"<table>";
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
        if($row1['topic_id'] == $row['topic_id']){
            echo "<tr><th><font color='blue'>".$row1['topic_name']."</th></tr> </font>";
            echo"<a href='postreply.php?cat_id='$cat_id'&topic_id='$topic_id'&topic_creator='$topic_creator''>hi</a>";
        }
    }
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['post_content']."</td></tr>";
    echo"</table><hr>";
}
```

Comment: Do `$cat_id`, `$topic_id`, and `$topic_creator` exist?

Comment: yes, everything works except when i click the link, nothing happens

Comment: Your `<a` is between table rows.  Try moving it inside one (with the quote fixes mentioned below): `<tr><td><a href='....'></td></tr>`

Answer (score 1):

Your quotations are breaking the code, 
You will need to escape the double quotes, so they will not be read as PHP code. You can do this by typing a `\` character before them.

In your above code, modify as follows:

```
echo"<a href='postreply.php?cat_id='$cat_id'&topic_id=\"$topic_id'&topic_creator=\"$topic_creator''>hi</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiple `'` are not needed and the space between `?` and `cat` as well may cause issues

```
echo"<a href='postreply.php?cat_id=$cat_id&topic_id=$topic_id&topic_creator=$topic_creator'>hi</a>";
```

Comment: What does the generated HTML look like when you `View Page Source` in your browser

Comment: i cant click the <a href link

Comment: But as I asked above, look at the page source on the browser, ans show us if it is not obvious to you what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Try with,

```
echo"<a href='postreply.php?cat_id=$cat_id&topic_id=$topic_id&topic_creator=$topic_creator'>hi</a>";
```

Your code is breaking due to the wrong usage of ' in the href attribute

**Edit :**

You are still not able to click the element since the parent element #notificationContainer click event listener has a return false which prevents the default action of children as well.

You can make the link working by either changing listener code that code or by stopping the event propagation from child a to parent  #notificationContainer. This will stop calling the parent click event listener and will allow the default action of the a element.

So either remove

```
$("#notificationContainer").click(function()
{
return false;
});
```

or add the below code for stopping propagation in the script.

```
$("#notificationContainer a").click(function(e)
{ 
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: @prozcay could you provide the generated html of your code?

Comment: Thanks now i can click but it runs back to the same page, instead of postreply.php:(

Comment: @prozcay on clicking it its going to http://bit-mp.biz/m05/studyarea/postreply.php?cat_id=&topic_id=&topic_creator=.     is this not what you want ?

Comment: onclick "hi" it is suppose to go to 'postreply.php?cat_id=$cat_id&topic_id=$topic_id&topic_creator=$topic_creator'

Comment: @prozcay I am checking the site link you provided and on clicking hi its going to the postreply.php page

Comment: @prozcay i can see the jQuery missing issues in the developer console. Could you check for those ?

Comment: may i know how do i check for it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `HTML` tags inside `php echo "<h1>Don't Use This</h1>";` because when you use these in bigger project these may create problem of indentation, omitting quot semicolon Etc. Try to keep your code in good Form.

On the other side i recommend you to use php classes and object, mysqli object oriented with prepared statement .These will help in better way of coding.

```
<?php    
if (mysql_num_rows($sql1)){
    ?>      
            <table>
    <?php
            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1)) {
                if($row1['topic_id'] == $row['topic_id']){
    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><font color='blue'><?php echo $row1['topic_name'];?></font></th>
                    </tr>
                    <a href="postreply.php?cat_id=<?php echo "cat_id=".$cat_id."&topic_id=".$topic_id."&topic_creator=".$topic_creator;?>">hi</a>
    <?php
                }
            }
    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['post_content'];?></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <hr>
    <?php
        }

    ?>
```